# How can I average a matrix every nth elements in a vectorized way?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, mean, bsxfun

In MATLAB, given a 36 x 17 matrix `A`, I want to average every 6th elements of each column, creating a 6 x 17 matrix `B`. I can achieve it using the following code:

```
A = rand(36, 17);

B = [mean(A(1:6:36,:)); mean(A(2:6:36,:)); mean(A(3:6:36,:)); mean(A(4:6:36,:)); mean(A(5:6:36,:)); mean(A(6:6:36,:))];
```

Although syntax is not excessively long, I was wondering if I could achieve the same result through a more compact, efficient way (i.e. using `bsxfun` or `arrayfun`?)

Comment: You can reshape to a 3d matrix and take the mean on one of the dimensions.

Comment: I doubt that arrayfun would be more efficient. Arrayfun in most cases is likely to be less efficient than a loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to basically split the first dim into two with the former of length `6` to have a `3D` array and then use [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) along the latter of those two, which would be second dim in the `3D` array and a final reshape/squeeze for `2D` output -

```
B = squeeze(mean(reshape(A,6,[],size(A,2)),2))
```

Answer (score 7):

For the curious, this can also be done with matrix multiplication (close in efficiency to [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620000/52738), even a little faster in some cases):

```
N = size(A, 1)/6;
B = (repmat(eye(6), 1, N)*A)./N;
```

Comment: Perhaps a little faster: `repmat(eye(6)/N, N, 1).'*A`

Comment: @LuisMendo: Reordering to remove transposes is a good idea, but moving the division "inside" the multiplication appears to create a slight loss of numerical accuracy (the results differ from Divakar's by amounts on the order of the machine precision `eps`, but are exactly equal when the division is "outside").

Comment: Who says that Divikar's answer is exact?

Comment: Note that `1.1 - (1.1/3 + 1.1/3 + 1.1/3) = 0` and `1.1-3.3/3 = eps`.

Comment: @m7913d: Well, Divakar is using the built-in `mean` function, which I'm taking as ground truth. Also, `eye(6)` contains only 0 and 1, which can be represented exactly without round-off, but `eye(6)/N` will introduce potential round-off errors right from the get-go before the matrix multiply. As an example, note that `sum(ones(1,6))/6` is not exactly equal to `sum(ones(1,6)/6)`.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, you can obtain the same result using a [2D convolution](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) as follows:

```
  n = 6; % average every n-th element
  C = zeros(size(A, 1) - n + 1, 1);
  C(1:n:size(A, 1), :) = 1/(size(A, 1) / n);
  B = conv2(A, C, 'valid');
```

Note that this result is probably less efficient than the answer based on reshaping to 3D as proposed by Divakar (and beaker in its comment), but more efficient than the original question.